# Write notes on Medical ID with HealthKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

Using the [Fit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Fit/Listings/README_md.html) sample project from Apple that implements HealthKit I can write some data like birthday, height, weight and others with `[HKHealthStore saveObject:]`. But how can I write other data like **Medical Notes,** **Conditions**, **Allergies & Reactions** that appear in **Medical ID** in Apple's Health application?

I can not find anything equivalent like `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight`, but to save these notes;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a new HKHealthStore object in HealthKit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797586/how-to-create-a-new-hkhealthstore-object-in-healthkit)

Comment: It is the same question. I know create an `HKHealthStore` object, the question was how to create a `Medial ID`, which is something totally different.

Comment: Yep. I accidentally selected this Q for closing. What I get for working on SO before coffee. Retracted close vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The HealthKit API does not provide access to Medical ID.  There is no API on iOS for changing the user's Medical ID.

Comment: @tshortli : can we write medical ID features from custom app?

Comment: No, Medical ID cannot be accessed or changed by an app from the App Store.